# Possible compatibility issues inheriting from a C struct

Tags: c++, c, language-interoperability

Background: We're implementing a dynamic library in C++ that extends the functionality of a C program.  For one of the main structs used in the C program, we would like to add our own library specific fields.  Currently when we need a new field, we ask nicely that the developers of the C program add a field for us and we end up having a massive casting mess.  I was wondering if we could instead do the following:

Header file of main program:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/* ... */
typedef struct ImportantStruct {
/* Definitions */
} ImportantStruct
/* ... */
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Our Header File:

```
//...
class ObjectType : public ImportantStruct {
// Our extra fields
}
//...
```

I guess I have two questions:

1) Is this even legal?

2) What problems does this create when the C program tries to use the struct part of the object?

Comment: Sounds like life would be much easier if you just use composition rather than inheritance...

Comment: What will you do with your C struct ? Are you just importing the C struct ? Normally, inheriting from C struct is ok - remember C code in a `extern "C"` is parsed by a C++ compiler...

Comment: I agree in theory that composition would be a much, much better solution.  And if I were doing this from scratch, I would use composition in a heartbeat.  The problem is that we currently have a `typedef ImportantStruct ObjectType` and many, many places that access fields directly.  If I changed the typedef to inheritance, those access would still be legal, and I get better control of the object lifecycles.  However, as there possibly other immediate advantages to composition, I'll definitely re-consider it as an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `ImportantStruct` is a POD structure (automatically it has standard layout), and since ObjectType doesn't have other base types and if it doesn't have virtual methods, it also has a standard layout. Therefore it can be used as a struct in C.

> 1) Is this even legal?

Yes, it is.

> 2) What problems does this create when the C program tries to use the struct part of the object?

If your c function doesn't try to over-write it, you are safe. You can overwrite it like this :

```
void foo( struct ImportantStruct *s )
{
 memset( s,0, sizeof(*s) );
}
```

If it does, then it depends on what is in ImportantStruct, and whether there are padded bytes.

Structure like this :

```
typedef struct {
  int a;
  char b;
} ImportantStruct;
```

might have padded bytes removed when made base class.

Anyway, I would use composition, and avoid any kind of problems. But you have to make sure it is the first member, and that the ObjectType has standard layout.

Answer (score 0):

The derived approach should work, just mind the resulting alignment.
I would not make assumptions on the resulting size/offsets in the "extended" POD. Some compilers may remove padding of the base class. So the derived C++ POD may be of different size from resp. extended flat C struct.

More details on the layout of derived objects: [c-data-alignment-member-order-inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006504/c-data-alignment-member-order-inheritance)

Also for your purposes of extending POD you may use `struct` keyword  over `class`. Not a big difference, just the struct members are public by default.
It also kind of expresses your POD-intent (though it's not enforced).