# Why different type of symbol occupies the same length?

Tags: c, object-files, nm

I compiled below code with cygwin GCC on a x64 machine:

```
gcc main.c -o main
```

(main.c)

```
long long mango = 13; // I also tried `char`, `short`, `int`
long melon = 2001;

void main()
{

}
```

Then I dump the symbol values with `nm`:

```
./main:0000000100402010 D mango
./main:0000000100402018 D melon
```

As I understand, a symbol's value just means its address. So the address for `mango` is `100402010`. And `melon` has address `100402018`. So `mango` should occupy 8 bytes.

I tried other types for `mango`, such as `char`, `int`, `short`. It is always 8 bytes occupied.

Why the size doesn't change?

### ADD 1

Thanks to the comment.

I just tried below code:

```
typedef struct{
    char a1;
    char a2;
    char a3;
    char a4;
    char a5;
} MyStruct;

MyStruct MyObj1={1,2,3,4,5};

MyStruct MyObj2={1,2,3,4,5};

long long mango = 13;
long melon = 2001;

void main()
{

}
```

And this time, `nm` shows me this:

```
./main:0000000100402020 D mango
./main:0000000100402028 D melon
./main:0000000100402010 D MyObj1
./main:0000000100402015 D MyObj2
```

`MyObj1` and `MyObj2` are 5 bytes separated. So it is indeed up to the compiler to decide the padding.

Comment: The address is not telling you anything about the size.

Comment: In main do: `printf("%zu %zu", sizeof(mango), sizeof(melon));`

Comment: @EugeneSh. If so, what does the symbol's value mean? Or how is the symbol's value *used*?

Comment: @smwikipedia it's possible that that is the address. What we're saying is that the address tells you nothing about the size. It's possible that `melon` has to be on an 8 byte boundary so there's padding added between the variables. But the compiler can do whatever it wants here.

Comment: Keep in mind that the compiler will align things on different boundaries and add padding as necessary. So there may be 1 byte size, 7 bytes padding in the case of a `char`. Use `sizeof` to determine sizes.

Comment: *"So the address for `mango` is `100402010`. And `melon` has address `100402018`. So `mango` should occupy 8 bytes."* -- No, this means that `mango` uses **no more than 8 bytes**. For performance reasons (imposed by the hardware), the values are stored in the memory aligned at the length of a processor word. For 64-bit processors, the memory address of any value is a multiple of 8 bytes (i.e. 64 bits). The compiler can be told to use a different alignment but you should have a good reason to do it.

Comment: Alignment rules are ABI specific and may required different alignment that expected simply by type size... See also https://www.codesynthesis.com/~boris/blog/2009/04/06/cxx-data-alignment-portability/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the *[GNU nm binary utilities: nm page](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/nm.html)*:

> The symbol value, in the radix selected by options (see below), or
>   hexadecimal by default. The symbol type. At least the following types
>   are used; others are, as well, depending on the object file format. If
>   lowercase, the symbol is usually local; if uppercase, the symbol is
>   global (external). There are however a few lowercase symbols that are
>   shown for special global symbols (u, v and w). Depending on `pragma` settings and default alignment boundaries, the distance between successive symbol address may be the exact value of the number of bytes for that symbol `type`, or it may include *[padding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7345133/why-do-we-have-alignment-padding-if-memory-is-byte-addressable)*, which increases the apparent *sizeof* the symbol.

```
A

    The symbol’s value is absolute, and will not be changed by further linking.
B
...
```

IMO the use of the word *value* in `nm` parlance is unfortunate, as in this context *value* is used to depict the symbol's address.  The *address* of a symbol (value) will not change.  But in normal C parlance, the *value* of a symbol does change, for example:

```
int i = 0; // the address for symbol i will remain constant
i = 10;    // but the value of the symbol i can change.
```

Regarding the size of addresses, the address of any symbol for a 64bit build will always have a size of 8 bytes, while the address of any symbol on a 32bit build will have a size of 4 bytes. These sizes do not change, and are not affected by assigning a *value* to the symbol assigned to them.

Regarding the distance in memory space that occurs between various symbols, this distance is affected both by the `type` of symbol, how it is *[aligned](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwjhufPglNjaAhWJkpAKHQSeBBkQFggpMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwr.informatik.uni-hamburg.de%2F_media%2Fteaching%2Fwintersemester_2013_2014%2Fepc-14-haase-svenhendrik-alignmentinc-paper.pdf&usg=AOvVaw1WG33d9DPS9yztZTFlLaf-)* along that implementations boundaries, and, as you have noted, compiler: *"So it is indeed up to the compiler to decide the padding."*  Depending on `pragma` settings and default alignment boundaries, *[padding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7345133/why-do-we-have-alignment-padding-if-memory-is-byte-addressable)* may cause the addresses for successive symbols to be a greater distance than that caused only by the combined *sizeof* values of the `type`, or `types` that define a particular symbol. (a very common occurrence for both `char` and `struct` type symbols).

Comment: Thanks. And I agree with you that *the word "value" in nm parlance is unfortunate*.