# Helping GCC with auto-vectorisation

Tags: c++, gcc, mingw, sse, vectorization

I have a shader I need to optimise (with lots of vector operations) and I am experimenting with SSE instructions in order to better understand the problem.

I have some very simple sample code. With the `USE_SSE` define it uses explicit SSE intrinsics; without it I'm hoping GCC will do the work for me. Auto-vectorisation feels a bit finicky but I'm hoping it will save me some hair.

Compiler and platform is: gcc 4.7.1 (tdm64), target x86_64-w64-mingw32 and Windows 7 on Ivy Bridge.

Here's the test code:

```
/*
    Include all the SIMD intrinsics.
*/
#ifdef USE_SSE
#include <x86intrin.h>
#endif
#include <cstdio>

#if   defined(__GNUG__) || defined(__clang__) 
    /* GCC & CLANG */

    #define SSVEC_FINLINE __attribute__((always_inline))

#elif defined(_WIN32) && defined(MSC_VER) 
    /* MSVC. */

    #define SSVEC_FINLINE __forceinline

#else
#error Unsupported platform.
#endif


#ifdef USE_SSE

    typedef __m128 vec4f;

    inline void addvec4f(vec4f &a, vec4f const &b)
    {
        a = _mm_add_ps(a, b);
    }

#else

    typedef float vec4f[4];

    inline void addvec4f(vec4f &a, vec4f const &b)
    {
        a[0] = a[0] + b[0];
        a[1] = a[1] + b[1];
        a[2] = a[2] + b[2];
        a[3] = a[3] + b[3];
    }

#endif

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int const count = 1e7;

    #ifdef USE_SSE
    printf("Using SSE.\n");
    #else
    printf("Not using SSE.\n");
    #endif

    vec4f data = {1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f};

    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    {
        vec4f val = {0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f};
        addvec4f(data, val);
    }

    float result[4] = {0};
    #ifdef USE_SSE
    _mm_store_ps(result, data);
    #else
    result[0] = data[0];
    result[1] = data[1];
    result[2] = data[2];
    result[3] = data[3];
    #endif

    printf("Result: %f %f %f %f\n", result[0], result[1], result[2], result[3]);

    return 0;
}
```

This is compiled with:

```
g++ -O3 ssetest.cpp -o nossetest.exe
g++ -O3 -DUSE_SSE ssetest.cpp -o ssetest.exe
```

Apart from the explicit SSE-version being a bit quicker there is no difference in output.

Here's the assembly for the loop, first explicit SSE:

```
.L3:
subl    $1, %eax
addps   %xmm1, %xmm0
jne .L3
```

It inlined the call. Nice, more or less just a straight up `_mm_add_ps`.

Array version:

```
.L3:
subl    $1, %eax
addss   %xmm0, %xmm1
addss   %xmm0, %xmm2
addss   %xmm0, %xmm3
addss   %xmm0, %xmm4
jne .L3
```

It is using SSE math alright, but on each array member. Not really desirable.

My question is, how can I help GCC so that it can better optimise the array version of `vec4f`?

*Any Linux specific tips is helpful too, that's where the real code will run.*

Comment: Be aware that `float result[4]` may not be 16-byte aligned on the stack - it happens to work in this instance, or `_mm_store_ps` would fault.

Answer (score 7):

This `LockLess` article on [Auto-vectorization with gcc 4.7](http://locklessinc.com/articles/vectorize/) is hands down the best article I have ever seen and I have spent a while looking for good articles on similar topics. They also have a lot of other [articles](http://locklessinc.com/articles/) that you may find very useful on similar subjects dealing all manners of low level software development.

Comment: Thanks for the link, trying the tips in that article but it seems really hard to get it auto-vectorised properly. Trying a struct right now, forced to be 16-byte aligned but the best I can do is 4 `addss` instructions.

Comment: @Skurmedel Agreed, I found this and other articles doing research when I was more actively expanding the SSE section of X86 wikibook. Have you look at intrinsics? I have been looking for some of the intrinsics material I had but I can not seem to dig it up anymore.

Answer (score 4):

Here is some tips based on your code to make gcc auto-vectorization works:

- **make the loop-upbound a const**. To vectorize, GCC need to split the loop by 4-iterations to fit in the SSE XMM register, which is 128-bit length. a const loop upper bound will help GCC make sure that the loop have plenty of iterations,  and the vectorization is profitable.
- **remove the `inline` keyword**. if the code is marked  as inline, GCC can not know whether the start point of the array is aligned without inter-procedure analysis which will not turned on by `-O3`.

  so, to make your code vectorized, your `addvec4f` function should be modified as the following:

  ```
  void addvec4f(vec4f &a, vec4f const &b)
  {
      int i = 0;
      for(;i < 4; i++)
        a[i] = a[i]+b[i];
  }
  ```

BTW:

- GCC also have flags to help you find out whether a loop have been vectorized. `-ftree-vectorizer-verbose=2`, higher number will have more output information, currently the value can be `0`,`1`,`2`.[Here](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/tree-ssa/vectorization.html) is the documentation of this flag, and some other related flag.
- **Be careful of the alignment**. The address of the array should be aligned, and the compiler can not know whether the address is aligned without running it.Usually, there will be a `bus error` if the data is not aligned. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13400694/why-does-instruction-data-alignment-exist/13411045#13411045) is the reason.

Comment: Thanks, gonna try your suggestions.

Comment: Seeing the details of what's going on in the call-site usually helps, not hurts.  Your argument for removing `inline` makes no sense.  `alignof(vec4f)` is 16, so the compiler can always assume a `vec4f&` is aligned; it would be UB if it wasn't.  Also, this function is a wrapper for what should be a single instruction; it would be a total disaster if it didn't actually inline, especially with args by reference.  (Although with x86-64 System V having no call-preserved XMM regs, it's only slightly better with by-value vector args and a return value.)