# improving memory alignment of a structure on 32 bit machine

Tags: c, memory, padding

Correct the alignment of structure below that is bad.

```
typedef struct{ 
char *string; // 4 byte (type of address int)

char temp; // 1 byte

short pick; // 2 byte

char temp2; // 1 byte

}hello;
```

- string = 4
- temp + pick + temp2(offset 7) = 1+2+1

answer given, good alignment is

```
char *string; // 4 byte (type of address int)

short pick; // 2 byte

char temp; // 1 byte

char temp2; // 1 byte
```

- string = 4
- pick + temp + temp2(offset 7) = 2+1+1

unable to understand the reason that says temp2 should be at offset 7 rather than 8. how? please help

Comment: which question and which answer are you referring to here? What is the platform you are referring to? char* is 4 bytes (32bit) or 8bytes (64bit) so not sure when you say 2 bytes

Comment: just edited the post, ignore the question and answer part, take it to be 32 bit platform..

Comment: it's still wrong: on 32bit platform the pointers are 4 bytes, int is always 4 bytes (irrespective of 32 or 64 bits). Short is 2 bytes and char is 1 byte

try reading thru this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms253949(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: @Sarang: int can be 64bits on 64bit platforms (ILP64).

Comment: thanks for the reference, you are right address is int and is 4 byte but still the offset of temp2 remains the same(7) in both cases..

Comment: @Mat: yes for that you will have to use int64_t as defined in stdint.h
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13604137/definition-of-int64-t

Comment: @mat, sarang - it is 32 bit platform not 64 bit..is the question in correct..or answer incorrect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|    string     | pick  | t1| t2|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Using `t1` for `temp` and `t2` for `temp2`, this is the revised layout.  The offset of `t2` is 7.

For the original structure on a system where n-byte quantities are n-byte aligned, the layout would be:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | A | B |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|    string     | t1|pad| pick  | t2|pad|pad|pad|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

That's because the 4-byte pointer needs to be 4-byte aligned, so an array of the structure needs each member to be a multiple of 4 bytes.

Thus, in the original structure, the offset of t2 would have been 8, not 7.

Comment: So, the offset of t2 remains 7 in both question and answer, that means the explanation given in answer to me was wrong. The memory of structure asked in question was already aligned. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, I can understand it, but still I'm unable to digest why a short type (i.e. pick) needs to start from an even address, if the memory alignment needs to be 4 bytes. or simply why do I need a pad between t1 and pick?

Comment: Because pick is a 2 byte variable so it should start from a 2 byte aligned boundary. It could either have started from slot 4 in pic above. But t1 is there and occupied an even byte. Now if you had a 1 byte variable it could have come in place of 5 (pad), but it is 2 byte, so it should start from an even address. This might help http://stackoverflow.com/a/16456405/986760

Comment: @fayyazki, I really appreciate your effort in explaining me the whole idea..but I'm afraid to re-frame my ques that is..if the 32 bit processor is going to read four bytes at a time then how does it make a difference if pick starts from 5th or 6th byte..or in other words, why do you need a 2 byte boundary if 4 byte boundary is already there? and how is 2 byte boundary going to help a 32-bit processor?

Comment: It's a question of the instruction set, and where it is easy to load the value into the correct place in the registers.  It's not much help if the 2-byte integer is in the middle 2 bytes of a 4-byte register; you'd have to shift it to be able to use it.  It's to avoid that sort of thing that chips impose the restrictions.