# Do I need to align memory for 6 byte struct?

Tags: c++, alignment, memory-alignment

I am working on an image processing project in C++.  I have the following struct to represent each pixel in my image.

```
struct Pixel16
{
        uint16_t red;
        uint16_t green;
        uint16_t blue;
}
```

The size of this struct is 6 bytes.  In my Image class I plan to have an array of most likely millions of these depending on the size of the image.  I was wondering if I need to be worried about memory alignment? Should I align the memory to be on 8 byte boundaries.  Will this increase the performance?

Comment: Unless you need to do some tricky things with `Pixel16`, an alignment of 6 bytes would just be fine.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/381244/purpose-of-memory-alignment and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006216/why-is-data-structure-alignment-important-for-performance. Memory access will probably benefit from alignment, however it depends on the processor architecture. You should run benchmarks to find out if it matters for your use case.

Comment: It depends on the compiler. Optimization will automatically align the data to 8 bytes for increased performance.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani: I don't believe it will alter the alignment in this case - in what compiler have you seen that?

Comment: And to the original question: Which gives better performance depends on exactly what you are doing to the Pixel16 struct - are you at any time using it as if it was a 64-bit integer? Or are you only ever reading the `red`, `green` and `blue` as 16-bit values.

Comment: @MatsPetersson: You are right. I don't know what I was thinking. I tested it with MSVC, it doesn't add pad. Oddly enough, when optimization is off, speed increases by 50% by manually adding pad. If optimization is on, adding pad has no effect.